# Double Triple-Click brings up Switcher -- how do I change this to revert Triple-Click to be middle click again?

Tags: unity, 16.04, touchpad, 16.10, application-switcher

Behavior in 16.04:
Triple-click is middle click (This is an assumption, I can't be certain it was actually middle clicking, but the behavior was consistent with middle clicking) and opens link in new background tab in Firefox. Switcher was/is tiny and looks like shit, but works fine.

Behavior after upgrade to 16.10:
Double Triple-Click (but interestingly not a single triple-click, nor a double double-click, nor a double single-click) brings up a very nice looking Switcher I would love to use with alt+tab. It looks great. It's not tiny and doesn't look like shit. It would be wonderful if my alt-tabbing used this switcher, because it's large enough to be visible, the background color is in keeping with Ubuntu's theme and matches the dock.

I would also very much like Triple-Click to go back to being middle click. I can't find anywhere to set this, and it's sad because I can't open links in new background tab in Firefox without that old functionality.

11/7: within the past couple days, I've noticed sometimes my pages are huge or small text. Ctrl + 0 puts zoom back to original. However, today I realized double-clicking (left click) is cycling font size between bigger, smaller, and original zoom. What causes this? Can I turn it off? I mention it because it may be related to these strange changes in triple-click behavior in firefox.

12/9: within the past 2 days, I can triple-click in firefox again. However, I have to be *very* careful with the right-most finger. It has to be in a very small area in the top right corner of the trackpad, or nothing happens.

1/12: Reinstalled 16.10 because old account would boot me out immediately after login. No tiny switcher, but still getting normal switcher on double triple-click, and still can't triple-click to open links in new tab in Firefox. I can middle click on a mouse, so this suggest that for some reason, triple-click on trackpad is NOT emulating middle click. FOUND SOLUTION: https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/5807p9/tip_for_ubuntu_1610_use_dconfeditor_to_allow_you/

Does anyone know where/why double triple-click is opening switcher??

Comment: I can confirm I'm getting this on Ubuntu 16.04 with a Dell XPS 9360.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution to the switcher problems.

The "tiny switcher" was CompizConfig Settings Manager's  Window Management > Application Switcher. Disable keys that activate it. It sucks.

Go to Ubuntu Unity Plugin > Switcher tab make sure keys are enabled there. That's the "very nice looking switcher" that most people probably just think of as Ubuntu's default switcher.

Still have absolutely no idea why double triple-clicking pulls up switcher.

Still don't know how to revert triple click to middle click / open link in new background tab.

Answer (score 0):

For the trackpad not middle-clicking in 16.10:
https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/5807p9/tip_for_ubuntu_1610_use_dconfeditor_to_allow_you/

Put this in `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/99-middle-button.conf`

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "touchpad"
    Driver "synaptics"
    MatchIsTouchpad "on"
    Option "TapButton1" "1"
    Option "TapButton2" "3"
    Option "TapButton3" "2"
EndSection
```

and disable "org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.mouse" using dconf-editor which will otherwise disable the middle mouse button.